# Trouble with a Farm production programming assignment

Tags: java

> Develop a top-down design and write a program to produce a bar chart
>   of gourmet-popcorn production for a cooperative farm group on a
>   farm-by-farm basis.
>
> The input to the program is a series of data sets, one per line, with
>   each set representing the production for one farm.
>       Each data set consists of the name of a farm. Followed by a comma and one or more spaces, a decimal number representing acres planted,
>   one or more spaces, and an integer representing the number of pint
>   jars of popcorn produced for that farm.
>       The output is a bar chart that identifies each farm and displays its production in pints of corn per acre.
>       The output is a single line for each farm, with the name of the farm starting in the first column on a line and the bar chart starting
>   in column 30. Each mark in the bar chart represents 25 pint jars of
>   popcorn per acre.
>       The production goal for the year is 500 jars per acre. A vertical bar should appear in the chart for farms with production that does not
>   meet this goal, and a special mark is used for farms with production
>   greater than or equal to 500 jars per acre.

For example, given the input file

```
Orville’s Acres, 114.8 43801
Hoffman’s Hills, 77.2 36229
Jiffy Quick Farm, 89.4 24812
Jolly Good Plantation, 183.2 104570
Organically Grown Inc., 45.5 14683
```

the output would be:

```
Popcorn Co-op
Production in Hundreds
of Pint Jars per Acre
Farm Name 1 2 3 4 5 6
---|---|---|---|---|---|
Orville's Acres *************** |
Hoffman's Hills ****************** |
Jiffy Quick Farm *********** |
Jolly Good Plantation *******************#**
Organically Grown Inc. ************ |
```

This is the code I have already it runs and prints the correct format but it has an exception error. I am trying to split a string up into the farm name then a double acres and finally a int jars. The input file is

```
Orville’s Acres, 114.8  43801
Hoffman’s Hills, 77.2  36229
Jiffy Quick Farm,       89.4  24812
Jolly Good Plantation,  183.2  104570
Organically Grown Inc., 45.5        14683
```

The reason for all the spaces is I want it just to read lines with data.

Here is my source code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Popcorn
{

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{

printHeading(); 

System.out.print("Input file name you want to read from: ");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    

String fileName = in.next();    //declares fileName a string that uses in as input

Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));  //Declares input as the fileName and reads the file in

int jars;
double acres;
String amount;
String farmName;
System.out.println();
System.out.println("\t\t\tPopcorn Co-op");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("\t\t\t\tProduction in Hundreds");
System.out.println("\t\t\t\tof Pint Jars per Acre");
System.out.println("Farm Name\t\t\t   1   2   3   4   5   6");
System.out.println("\t\t\t\t---|---|---|---|---|---|");


while (input.hasNextLine())
{


    String inputLine = input.nextLine();    

    if (inputLine.isEmpty())
    {   

    }
    else 
    {
        farmName = inputLine.substring(0,inputLine.indexOf(','));
        String inputLine2 =  inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf(','),inputLine.length());
        Scanner line = new Scanner(inputLine2);
        acres = line.nextDouble();
        jars = line.nextInt();
        System.out.println(farmName + jars + acres);

    }

  }
}

private static void printHeading(){


System.out.println("Name");  //this assigns what printHeading will print
System.out.println("CSC 201-55468 Section 01PR");
System.out.println("Fall 2012");
System.out.println("Popcorn Project");
System.out.println();
  }

}
```

Comment: Always post the stacktrace for the exception

Comment: how would i go about that?

Comment: The exception that pops up in your console should contain method names and line numbers. The entire block of text in red is the stack trace. Post that here

Comment: "exception error" does not make any sense - there are _exceptions_ and _errors_, these are two completely different things. Also : there is no visible question, all you did was posting your homework whilst mentioning that there "is an exception [error]"

Comment: 4 warnings found:

File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\week 8\Popcorn.java  [line: 14]
Warning: Resource leak: 'in' is never closed

File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\J Sargeant Reynolds\csc201\week 8\Popcorn.java  [line: 18]

Warning: Resource leak: 'input' is never closed
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\J Sargeant Reynolds\csc201\week 8\Popcorn.java  [line: 22]

Warning: The value of the local variable amount is not used
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\J Sargeant Reynolds\csc201\week 8\Popcorn.java  [line: 47]

Warning: Resource leak: 'line' is never closed

Comment: @user3288334 those are just warnings thrown by the compiler, this won't stop compilation. After the `while` loop, put `in.close();` and those should stop appearing.

Answer (score -1):

You must close readers and buffers in java in order to have a clean resolution of main.  Simply add scannername.close(); and that should clear up your issues.  I believe this is in place to prevent corrupted files.

Comment: Files opened for _read_ do not get corrupted, and in general closing them in a small program is optional.